# Информация от группы RadioButton в JavaFX 8

Tags: java, gui, javafx

Хочу сделать RadioButton'ы в приложении, которые меняют картинку на экране. Не могу понять как получать информацию о нажатии на них.

**Tак я их создал и присвоил информацию о них:**

```
    ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup(); // Группа для RadioButton'ов

    RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton("Home");
    RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton("Work");
    RadioButton rb3 = new RadioButton("Rest");

    rb1.setToggleGroup(group);
    rb2.setToggleGroup(group);
    rb3.setToggleGroup(group);

    rb1.setUserData("Home");
    rb2.setUserData("Work");
    rb3.setUserData("Rest");
```

**После чего пытаюсь прочитать информацию о выборе нужного RadioButton:**

```
        group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(event -> {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(group.getSelectedToggle().getUserData() + ".png"));
        });
```

В консоль выводится null при нажатии любого RadioButton.

Весь листинг программы [тут](https://github.com/Faoxis/DemoJavaFx/blob/master/src/main/java/com/faoxis/javafx/lessons/lesson5/Main.java).

Comment: А вывод в консоль group.getSelectedToggle().getUserData() + ".png" нормально все выводит?

Comment: скорее всего `getResourceAsStream` не находит файлы (на гитхабе их вообще нигде нет). Если бы `getSelectedToggle` возвращал `null`, все бы падало.

Comment: Я создавал проект под Maven, а не JavaFx. Есть вероятность, что чего-то не хватает проекту.